# Compare different rows and make them one at tableview - Firebase/Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in Swift 3 and Firebase programming, but I am making good progress. But sometimes things come harder and here I am again because I could not find some text as specifically as I need, neither updated for Swift 3. I have tried many many ways.

The issue is that I am building an app for some teachers to make a kind of examination with their students. Each Student has the same examination by two different teachers at different times and the results are shown at a table view controller like the following image:

[image: Main tableview]

As you can see, I have two rows for each student with two different scores (partial). What I wish is to filter this Firebase data, search for those two “repeated” students and make an average score from them and show the data at a table view controller (exam1 + exam2 / 2) for the final average score. This is my currently Firebase structure (I will post an alternative later at this question):

[image: Firebase currently structure]

Now, parts of the code:
1.  Struct for variables and snapshot

```
import Foundation
import Firebase

struct Examination {

    var nome: String?
    var preceptor: String?
    var dataHoje: String?
    var nota: String?
    var key: String?

    init(nome: String, preceptor: String, nota: String, dataHoje: String, key: String) {
        self.nome = nome
        self.preceptor = preceptor
        self.nota = nota
        self.dataHoje = dataHoje
        self.key = key
    }

    init(snapshot: FIRDataSnapshot) {
        key = snapshot.key
        let snapshotValue = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject]
        nome = snapshotValue?["nome"] as? String
        preceptor = snapshotValue?["preceptor"] as? String
        nota = snapshotValue?["nota"] as? String
        dataHoje = snapshotValue?["dataHoje"] as? String
        notaAtitude = snapshotValue?["notaAtitude"] as? String

    }

    func toAnyObject() -> Any {
        return [
            "nome": nome,
            "preceptor": preceptor,
            "nota": nota,
            "dataHoje": dataHoje,
            "userKey": key,
        ]
    }

}
```

Load method for main table view controller

```
import Foundation
import Firebase
var refAlunos: [Examination] = []

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)
        Load_HM1()
}

func Load_HM1() {
    let refW = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("semestre_1_2017").child("avaliacaoHM12017").child("cheklists")
    refW.queryOrdered(byChild: "nome").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

        var newTeste2: [Examination] = []
        for resposta in snapshot.children {
            let itemsAadicionar = Examination(snapshot: resposta as! FIRDataSnapshot)
            newTeste2.append(itemsAadicionar)
        }
        self.refAlunos = newTeste2
})
  }
```

At last, the Firebase structure I have also tried, but I always receive nil as result, table view empty:

[image: Optional structure]

The code for this alternative way (method load), I could not implement:

```
func Load_HM1() {
        let refW = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("semestre_1_2017").child("avaliacaoHM12017").child("cheklists") ... I CRASHED HERE..
```

// The rest of this method is the same shown before

So, resuming the issue, I need a way to compare rows with the same student name (always will be 2) and calculate the average of these two scores and publish a table view with this final score and name, almost as the first image, but only changing the score to the final average. I really don’t know if there is a way and I don’t know which way to go. I have searched a lot, but nothing found. I guess this second firebase structure could be more friendly, but my rows are empty. If need more information to understand this issue, ask me that I update the question. Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of Firebase providing such functionalities out of the box, therefore I would recommend doing your calculations manually.

Before setting `self.refAlunos` at the end of the callback function you can extract the corresponding pairs of examinations, compute the average grade for each pair and create a new instance containing the computed average grade and the remaining attributes. Afterwards you can store an array of the generated examinations in `self.refAlunos`.

Additionally, you should take a look at [Structure Your Database](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/structure-data) and [Structuring your firebase data](https://www.airpair.com/firebase/posts/structuring-your-firebase-data). Applying these guidelines will help to flatten your data and improve performance as your data grows.

**Edit:**

I'm currently not on my Mac, but I hope my suggestions can point you in the right direction, although they might not be 100% syntactically correct.

```
func Load_HM1() {
let refW = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("semestre_1_2017").child("avaliacaoHM12017").child("cheklists")
refW.queryOrdered(byChild: "nome").observe(.value, with: {(snapshot) in

    var newTeste2: [Examination] = []

    var examinations: [Examination] = []
    var position = -1

    for resposta in snapshot.children {
        let itemsAadicionar = Examination(snapshot: resposta as! FIRDataSnapshot)
        newTeste2.append(itemsAadicionar)
        for exam in 0..<examinations.count {
            if (examinations[exam].nome == itemsAadicionar.nome) {
                position = exam
                break
            }
        }
        if (position != -1) {
            examinations[position].nota += itemsAadicionar.nota
            examinations[position].nota /= 2
            position = -1
        }
    }
    self.refAlunos = examinations
 })
}
```

I have edited your code and I hope you will get the gist. However, this approach is only suitable if you always have two exams per student. If you have more, you need to adapt it a little bit.

Comment: Ok, thanks @alex, but how do i "extract the corresponding pairs of examinations" and "store an array" with these new one? Could you help here?

Comment: Hi @alex, thanks for your help. I understood your idea and I am trying to make it works. This solution helped me to solve other issues too. But specifically here, it returns a swift compile error at the two lines just below: `if (position != -1)`. This is the message:  "Cannot subscript a value of type inout [Examination]' (aka ínout Array<Examination>'). I don't know what this could be. If you have any idea again it would be nice. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Hi @IvanSinigaglia, I just took another look at your definition of an exam. You store nota as a String although I assumed it was a float value. Therefore you need to cast your value as a number, perform the necessary calculations and store it as a string.